# Laplace transform for solving differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I am confused about Laplace transform. the only thing that is important in Laplace theorem is the value of $f(t)$ in $t \geq 0$.

laplace transform:

$\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}$ $=$ $\int_0^\infty \! e^{-st}f(t)$

so as we see in the above transform $f(t)$ if $t<0$ is not important at all. so do we find the answer for only $t > 0$ or the answer is correct in $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so do we find the answer for only $t > 0$ or the answer is correct in $\mathbb{R}$?

In your setting, yes you will find your transform for $t \geq 0$.
If you're interested in $\mathbb{R}$ you do $$ F(s) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-st} f(t)$$ which is also known as Bilateral (2-sided) Laplace transform.

Comment: so you say that Laplace transform gives the answer for $t>0$ but I have seen that it is used for $R$. is there a condition so that the answer from Laplace transform is correct in $R$

Comment: what do you exactly mean by "the answer from Laplace" ???? That does not make any sense. I tried to answer your question to the closest logical question possible.

Comment: we apply Laplace transform to an equation and find an answer. the phrase  "the answer from Laplace"  means this answer

Comment: so once you solve a diff. eqn using Laplace you obtain the answer in Laplace domain .. and then you apply Laplace inverse to go back to time domain. Do you mean that answer ?

Comment: exactly. you got the point

Comment: well if the negative counterpart of the integration turns out to be zero, then you can say that my function works for all $t$, namely when $ \int_{-\infty}^0 e^{-st} f(t) = 0$

Comment: I think you are wrong $\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{-st} f(t)$ is infinitie most of the time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88127/discussion-between-ahmad-bazzi-and-jack-math).